# What horrible taste VS what a horrible taste

Tags: meaning

Am I right, if I interpret the former as their liking is bad, and the latter as something tastes bitter or bad?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.  I could imagine sentences in which they might have the opposite meanings, but your interpretation is the more natural one.

Comment: @stangdon Could you tell if the indefinite article in "**a** great taste" means "a great sensation of taste"?

Comment: OP, you are correct.

Comment: @AydenFerguson Yes, I would say it usually means "a great sensation of taste".  The only way I can think of using **a taste** and having it mean the other meaning is in something like, "He had **a horrible taste** in friends."

Comment: @stangdon That helped :-). One last question, in your last example "He had a horrible taste in friends", does the indefinite article in "**a** horrible taste" mean "a type of taste which is horrible"?

Comment: @AydenFerguson Yes, that is how I would describe it.  *Taste* meaning "preferences" or "sense of discrimination" usually has no article, but we can use the indefinite article to mean a specific case of it.

Comment: @stangdon I realize that there shouldn’t be any article in “he had a horrible taste in friends”. It should be “he had horrible taste in friends”.